# User current location annotation not being shown on SKMapView (Skobbler) - iOS

Tags: ios, maps, skmaps, skobbler-maps

In my iOS project I'm using skobbler's SKMapView, I need to show user's current location with an annotation on mapview. I tried following code to do the same :

```
    mapView.settings.followUserPosition = true
    mapView.settings.showCurrentPosition = true
```

And I have location access in the app (WhenInUse Location access).But the annotation is not being shown. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have contacted the skobbler team, following things should be ensured to get the user's current location

1. Add NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription in Info plist.
2. Set show current position as true

   ```
   mapView.settings.showCurrentPosition = true
   ```
3. Request location update from SKPositionerService

   ```
   SKPositionerService.sharedInstance().startLocationUpdate()
   ```